# Excel: How To Transpose Every Random amount of N Rows From One Column To Multiple Columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a set of multiple choices questions with ABCD as answers, all answers are stacked on a column, but not every question has the same amount of answers.

Instead of transposing every nth value, my sheet has a random number of rows with answers(2-5), and between those data are a random amount of empty rows(2-3). How do I transpose all of those rows to clean columns?

basically from
[original col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmdC0.png)
to
[sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOHfv.png)

Comment: Filter columns?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your questions do not have a set amount of answers and the fact that empty lines vary between 1 and 2 between questions, you have to match the nth instance of A-E.
I'd prefer to go with offsets, but with your setting, this is done by an array formula, that's [nicely described here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html#:%7E:text=To%20find%20the%20second%20match,%2B%20Shift%20%2B%20Enter%20keys%20simultaneously.).

I don't see the coordinates for your cells, so I'll be referring my replica of your workbook:
[image]

- In column **A** I have ABCD choices, empty lines and some text in-between them.
- In column **B** I have the actual answers to choices.
- Column **C** is used for a question number.
- Columns **DEFGH** are the choices as per your second screenshot.

The fun part comes below the last mentioned columns. Formula will be like:
`{=INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF(D$1=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)-ROW($A$1)+1),$C2))}`
It should be typed with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, as it's an array formula. Once typed you may copy-paste it to the other cells.

You'll have to readjust this formula for you workbook. There aren't many variables here:

- $B:$B — question answers.
- $A:$A — used twice in this formula. Responds to your first screenshot and first column, the choices keys.
- $A$1 — first cell in the above mentioned column that will be shifted.
- $C2 — question numbers frozen at column.
- D$1 — choices in the header just as on your second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//Change next line to reflect actual Column Names
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),

//Split column 1 into two columns to separate questions and the answer letter
    newTable = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.Transform(#"Removed Blank Rows"[Column1], each if List.Contains({"A".."Z"}, _) then null else _ )} &
        {List.Transform(#"Removed Blank Rows"[Column1], each if List.Contains({"A".."Z"}, _) then _ else null)} & 
        {#"Removed Blank Rows"[Column2]},
        type table[Question=nullable text, Answer Letter=nullable text, Answer text=nullable text]),

//Fill down the Questions column and remove the rows containing nulls in the Answer letter column
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(newTable,{"Question"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Answer Letter] <> null)),

//Pivot on the Answer letter column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[#"Answer Letter"]), "Answer Letter", "Answer text")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with the solutions already given. If you still have not completed the task manually, but are waiting for a ready-made solution, then I will offer my own version.

Turn on macro recording.

Specify the "hot key" you will use to launch (for example, **Ctrl-g**)

Start pressing the buttons in a sequence that should lead you to copy and transpose one group of answers in the right place:

```
Ctrl-Home, 
Right Arrow, 
Ctrl-Down Arrow, 
Ctrl-Shift-Down Arrow (the first group of questions is highlighted), 
Ctrl-C (copy to clipboard), 
Ctrl-End, 
Ctrl-Left Arrow, 
Ctrl-Alt-V (specify "transposed"), 
Enter, 
and again Ctrl-Home, 
Right Arrow, 
Ctrl-Down Arrow, 
Ctrl-Shift-Down Arrow 
and Delete (the first group of questions is deleted).
```

Stop macro recording.

*You may need to change one or two lines of code to select first empty cell at the end of table. Somethig like as*

```
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Range("A" & (Selection.Row + 1)).Select
```

*I hope that the nickname you have chosen indicates that this will not be a problem for you.*

Now press **Ctrl-g** until you reach the end of the list. Column B is now cleared and all the answers from it are collected in the table at the bottom of the page.